# How do I right-click on an image and Copy image address using selenium C#?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

How do I right-click on an image and Copy image address using selenium C#?

I used this code:

```
var productimgs = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='coconut-baby-organic']/div[1]/div[1]/div/a/div/img"));
            Actions action = new Actions(driver);
            action.ContextClick(productimgs).Build().Perform();
            action.SendKeys(Keys.ArrowDown).Build().Perform();
            action.SendKeys(Keys.ArrowDown).Build().Perform();
            action.SendKeys(Keys.ArrowDown).Build().Perform();
            action.SendKeys(Keys.ArrowDown).Build().Perform();
            action.SendKeys(Keys.Enter).Build().Perform();
```

I expect it to right-click on the image and keep going down till it finds "Copy image address" then click it but it's not.

Comment: You might consider using Selenium to get the SRC: String src_value = productimgs.getAttribute("src");

Comment: The answer from EylM points out that you won't be able to use the menu in chrome. Is there a specific reason you need to use the right click menu rather then getting the link directly from selenium?

Comment: No, I figured that we just need to get the image src attribute, btw, thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1003) in the Chrome Selenium Web driver.

Alternatives:

1. Use Firebox web driver.
2. You can achieve a similar functionality, using the [inputsimulator](https://github.com/michaelnoonan/inputsimulator). Note: The Chrome window must be in focus.

   ```
   // find the element and click on it.
   IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("some_xpath"));
   Actions action = new Actions(driver);
   action.ContextClick(element).Build().Perform();

   // navigate in menu
   var input = new InputSimulator();
   input.Keyboard.KeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.DOWN);
   input.Keyboard.KeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.DOWN);
   input.Keyboard.KeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.DOWN);
   input.Keyboard.KeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.DOWN);
   input.Keyboard.KeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.RETURN);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Why on earth you want to do this using context click? The approach will require browser constantly being in focus, it means that you will not be able to do anything else with your computer while the test is running, neither you will be able to [run your Selenium tests in parallel mode](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Parallel+Tests+-+Best+Practices).

Instead I would recommend fetching [`src` attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_src.asp) of the [`<img>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) - that would be the URL you're looking for. It can be done via [IWebElement.GetAttribute()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement_GetAttribute.htm) function

Example code:

```
var productimgs = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='coconut-baby-organic']/div[1]/div[1]/div/a/div/img"));
var src = productimgs.GetAttribute("src");
Console.WriteLine("Image URL is: " + src);
```